# Creating PNG images using QGIS 3 pygis

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, plot

Some days ago I upgraded from QGIS 2.18 to 3.6.0 - not knowing that many Python scripts won't run without modifications.

I could convert all of them but not this one:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui 
import processing, sys, time, psycopg2
import pprint

...
creatin layers skipped (got this running)
...

################### Create Graph #####################

mapRenderer = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()

layers = [missingLayer.id(),clipLayer.id()]
mapRenderer.setLayerSet(layers)

c = QgsComposition(mapRenderer)
c.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)

c.setPaperSize(148,90)
c.setPrintResolution(300)

# add map
x, y = 0, 0
w, h = c.paperWidth(), c.paperHeight()
composerMap = QgsComposerMap(c, x,y,w,h)
c.addItem(composerMap)

#output to image
dpi = c.printResolution()
dpmm = dpi / 25.4
width = int(dpmm * c.paperWidth())
height = int(dpmm * c.paperHeight())

BackgroundColor = QColor(0,0,255)

# create output image and initialize it
image = QImage(QSize(width, height), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
image.setDotsPerMeterX(dpmm * 1000)
image.setDotsPerMeterY(dpmm * 1000)
image.fill(BackgroundColor)

header = QgsComposerLabel(c)
header.setItemPosition(40,1)
header.setBackgroundEnabled(0)
newFont = QFont("Comic Sans MS", 18)
header.setFont(newFont)
header.setText("Missing Countries Map")
header.adjustSizeToText()
c.addItem(header)

header2 = QgsComposerLabel(c)
header2.setItemPosition(50,11)
header2.setBackgroundEnabled(0)
newFont2 = QFont("Comic Sans MS", 10)
header2.setFont(newFont2)
header2.setText("TS="+ts)
header2.adjustSizeToText()
c.addItem(header2)

footer = QgsComposerLabel(c)
footer.setItemPosition(124,87.5)
footer.setBackgroundEnabled(0)
newFont3 = QFont("Times Roman", 4)
footer.setFont(newFont3)
footer.setText(time.ctime())
footer.adjustSizeToText()
c.addItem(footer)

legend = QgsComposerLegend(c)
legend.model().setLayerSet(mapRenderer.layerSet())
legend.setItemPosition(5,65)
legend.setFrameEnabled(1)
newFont = QFont("Comic Sans MS", 6)
legend.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Title, newFont)
legend.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Subgroup, newFont)
legend.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.SymbolLabel, newFont)
legend.setStyleMargin(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Title,2)
legend.setTitle("Legend")
legend.setSymbolHeight(2)
legend.adjustBoxSize()
c.addItem(legend)

# render the composition
imagePainter = QPainter(image)
imagePainter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
sourceArea = QRectF(0, 0, c.paperWidth(), c.paperHeight())
targetArea = QRectF(0, 0, width, height)
c.render(imagePainter, targetArea, sourceArea)
imagePainter.end()
imageFile = "missing_boundaries"+ts+".png"
print "saving to "+imageFile
image.save(imageFile)
```

Yes, I do know the QqsComposer has gone but I can't find any documentation or example for QGIS3 plotting. Except the API description of course.

I don't need the whole script converted - only a hint how to open/create a png the new way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your layout done, you can export it as PNG :

```
layoutManager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
layout = layoutManager.layoutByName("your_layout_name")
```

Example of accessing items :

I have called the legend `legend` as item id, so :

```
legend_layout = layout.itemById('legend')
legend_layout.setTitle('layout_title_label')
legend_layout.refresh()

# EXPORTING

pdf_path = os.path.join( QgsProject.instance().homePath(), "{}.pdf".format(filename))  #
png_path = os.path.join( QgsProject.instance().homePath(), "{}.png".format(filename))

# you need to create an exported layout object
exporter_layout = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)

exporter_layout.exportToPdf(pdf_path, QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
exporter_layout.exportToImage(png_path, QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())
```

Hope it helps ;)

For code to export, see PyQGIS developer cookbook, *Output using print layout*

- [Exporting the layout](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html#output-using-print-layout).